# How can I convert VRLM files to 3D PDF ? (python or freeware)

Tags: pdf, 3d

I would take an answer for either way, either using Python libraries or a freeware utility. 
I have come across U3D-2-PDF but it seems that the project was abandoned and follow the instructions did not work (receiving an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design Spark Mechanical solved my problem (freeware)
I was trying to get from Sketchup to 3D PDF via VRLM.
This software imports Skp files and exports them as 3D PDF

Answer (score 0):

It is not free, but you can get a free trial at Tetra4d.com for their Converter tool. You can convert all major CAD formats to 3D PDF.